# Club-Mate doesn't fit Club-Mate in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my Stack:

- Rails 3.2.6
- MongoID ~> 2.5
- Tire 0.4.2
- ElasticSearch Server

I have a couple thousand products I want to index in elastic search. This is my mapping:

```
mapping do
    indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100
    indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball'
end
```

Unfortunately the search results are unbelievable bad. By searching for "club-mate", the first result is "club-mate-c". And the second result is "club-mate". Why is "club-mate" not the best fit to "club-mate". 
The search results are ordered by _score. Nothing else.

I appreciate any kind of feedback. 
I am sure it is just a configuration problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided little information about what data you are indexing, how uniform the data is, or how you are querying it.

A likely problem is that the terms `club` and `mate` are not very common in your dataset, and are unevenly distributed across your shards.

By default, the term frequencies are considered separately by each shard, so if on one shard you have `club`, `mate` 3 times, and on another shard you have `club`, `mate`, `c` once, then the second shard might consider `club` and `mate` to be more relevant than the first shard.

Typically, with large amounts of data, term frequencies even themselves out, so this ceases to be a problem.  However, with small amounts of data, you can see issues like this.

Solutions:

- Use a single shard instead of the default 5 (if you are always going to have a small amount of data, then this is the better option)
- Index more data
- Add `search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch` to your search parameters, which will check the term frequencies across all shards before running the query

**Note:** The `search_type` defaults to `query_then_fetch` rather than to `dfs_query_then_fetch` because normally, you would have enough data to ensure even term frequencies, and it performs better.

You can add `explain=1` to your search parameters to see how the score for each document has been calculated, which should shed more light on the problem.

Comment: Great answer Clinton, as always!

Comment: Many thanks for you answer. I have round about 140K documents in the index. And many names are duplicated. I played a little bit around with the index. I realized that as more attributes I add to the index, as worst the results. If I index only the name, and nothing else, then the search works like expected. But as soon I am adding description and other fields to the index, the search results become really bad.

Comment: Then you need to provide examples of "bad" queries and results with explain=1, and it would help if you provided the actual mapping stored in ES, rather than the tire config

Comment: It sounds like you are querying the _all field rather than the specific fields that you are interested in.  Without more information, difficult to give better advice.

Comment: @DrTech I just tried it again with the new version of Tire. And I changed the sorting to: "search.sort { by [{:name => 'desc'}] }" and that delivered the results I was looking for. But your are right! I am querying _all fields. How can I do it more specific?

Comment: @DrTech Actually "dfs_query_and_fetch" solved the problem. Many Thanks for the hint.